# Entity Framework Code First - Database Initializer - Seed method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, integration-testing

I'm currently developping a small tool to perform integration tests against a database using Entity Framework Code First.

But, the problem is that my seed method is not executed when the database is created.

The tool is written so that on every test, the database is dropped and recreated.

First of all, I've the context that my tests are runt on:

```
public class IntegrationArrangeActAssert<T> : ArrangeActAssert where T : DbContext
{
    #region Properties

    protected T context { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region ArrangeActAssert Members

    /// <summary>
    ///     Set up the current state of the specs context.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void Arrange()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<T>());
        context.Database.Initialize(true);

        base.Arrange();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Then, my class that holds my unit test is just inheriting from this class.

Now, when I run a unit test, the seed method in the configuration of T is not executed. The database is created, the migrations are executed, but I just don't get any data in my database.

It's quite an important part to run integration tests.

Anyone who knows why the seed method doesn't work?

Comment: you're leaving something out here. You're setting DropCreateDatabaseAlways, which is part of Entity Framework. Why would you expect the Seed() OF DropCreateDatabaseAlways() class to fill any data? It doesn't.  Write your own initializer, inheriting from DropCreateDatabaseAlways and override Seed().

Comment: Thanks. I thought it was something simple. Don't understand why I haven't found that myself.